# Finding dual basis to some given basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone briefly explain me how to find dual basis to some given basis?
Let's say we've got $n$-dimensional linear space with given basis $(e_1,e_2,...,e_n)$. How to find $(e_1^*, e_2^*, ...., e_n^*)$?

Comment: What do you mean by "find" $e_i^{\ast}$?  You already know what it is, it is the function $V \rightarrow k$ given by $c_1e_1 + \cdots + c_ne_n \mapsto c_i$.

Comment: I don;t exactly understand $c_1e_1 + \cdots + c_ne_n \mapsto c_i$. I want to literally show those functions from basis.

Comment: So you don't understand the definition of the functions $e_i^{\ast}$?

Comment: I do understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the vectors $e_i$ in the columns of some matrix $A$. If you have a matrix $B$ having as columns the vectors $e_i^*$, then $B^*A=I$, where $B^*$ is the transpose of $B$. Hence, $B=(A^{-1})^*$.

So, the elements of the dual basis are the columns of the matrix $(A^{-1})^*$.

Comment: Great construction, but I have to find $A^{-1}$, which can be tricky.

Comment: Not only you, but anybody who wants the dual basis! :-) You cannot escape from it.

Comment: Really? I'll give you an example below to find out if I understand it correctly.

Comment: This assumes that A is a square matrix. How would you obtain the dual basis when A is an $n$ by $k$ matrix?

Answer (score 4):

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $k$ with basis $e_1, ...  e_n$.  The dual $V^{\ast}$ is defined to be the vector space consisting of all linear transformations from $V$ to $k$.  The definitions of addition and scalar multiplication in $V^{\ast}$ are obvious, as is the fact that $V^{\ast}$ is actually a vector space.

Every element in $V$ can be uniquely written as a sum $c_1e_1 + \cdots + c_ne_n$, where $c_i$ are in $k$.  For each $j$, define a function $e_j^{\ast}: V \rightarrow k$ by the formula $$e_j^{\ast}(c_1e_1 + \cdots + e_nv_n) = c_j$$  You can check that for any $x, y \in V$, and any $c \in k$, that $e_j^{\ast}(x+y) = e_j^{\ast}(x) + e_j^{\ast}(y)$, and $e_j^{\ast}(cx) = c e_j^{\ast}(x)$.  In other words, $e_j^{\ast}$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $k$, so $e_j^{\ast} \in V^{\ast}$.

The basic result is that the elements $e_i^{\ast}$ form a basis for the vector space $V^{\ast}$.  Is this what you're having trouble proving?

Comment: I don't want to prove anything, I just want to know algorithm for calculation dual basis from given basis.

Comment: look at my answer below. That is the only way to literally show dual basis, right?

Comment: You seem to be learning this in a different way than I did.  To me, dual bases a priori don't have anything to do with matrices.  I don't understand the answers other people are providing, or what they are trying to show.

Comment: Okay, so please do the task below in you'r way. Show me literally that dual basis like I did.

Comment: I don't want to write the rest of the details out, but I've already "literally" shown you the dual basis $e_1^{\ast}, ... , e_n^{\ast}$; they are elements of $V^{\ast}$, and I've defined exactly what they are.  The only thing left to do is to show that $e_1^{\ast}, ... , e_n^{\ast}$ do, in fact, form a basis: one must argue that they are linearly independent and they span $V^{\ast}$.

Comment: I'm sorry to have confused you on this.  When you say "dual basis" of a given basis $e_1, ... , e_n$, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Exactly what you wrote. I understand dual basis as basis of dual space $V^*$. We can calculate it with given some basis of $V$. And that was the point of my question - what is the algorithm to do that.

Comment: I mean "literally" as: show me the output of your algorithm with given input as below. The output should be: $((\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}), (\frac{1}{2}x -\frac{1}{2}), (\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}x))$.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  A dual basis is a dual basis.  There is nothing to calculate, unless you are writing that basis in terms of some other preexisting basis.

Answer (score 2):

Okej, so let's suppose we've got $([1,1,1],[1,1,-1],[1,-1,-1])$, some basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. That's how I can generate dual basis:
Let
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1  &1 \\ 
1 &1  &-1 \\ 
1 &-1  &-1 
\end{bmatrix}
be the $A$ matrix. I have to find $A^{-1}$, which is
\begin{bmatrix}
0,5 &0  &0,5 \\ 
0 &0,5  &-0,5 \\ 
0,5 &-0,5  &0 
\end{bmatrix}
And that's all. Dual basis is $((\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}), (\frac{1}{2}x -\frac{1}{2}), (\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}x))$
Right? And I cannot avoid calculation $A^{-1}$, right?

Comment: All exactly as you wrote.

Comment: Thank you! That's clear now.