# Interpreting dual basis vectors given basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I was searching for how to find the elements of the dual basis for some vector space $V$ given the basis for $V$ and I found this ([Finding dual basis to some given basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628303/finding-dual-basis-to-some-given-basis)). I'm now trying to compute some simple examples and I have difficulties in interpreting the results.

Say I have the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and vectors $(1,0)^T$ and $(1,1)^T$, then according to the links answer the dual basis should be the columns of $$\left(\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ \:0&1\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\right)^T = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ -1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

but these are vectors and not functions from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. How should this be interpreted correctly?

Comment: Vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$ correspond to linear forms on $\mathbb{R}^2$ via the dot product.

Answer (score 5):

If you represent elements of $V$ by column vectors, then you should represent elements of $V^*$ by row vectors (and the pairing of an element of $V^*$ with an element of $V$ is given by multiplication of the row by the column to get a scalar).

We start with a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and we want the dual basis $\{\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n\}$. This is determined by the conditions $\phi_i(v_j) = \delta_{ij}$ ($1$ if $i=j$, $0$ otherwise).

If your original vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are inserted as the columns of $A$, then we seek a matrix $B$ so that $BA = I$. The rows of $B$ will then be the dual basis vectors. You recognize $B$ as the inverse matrix $A^{-1}$.  The link you found takes the transpose in order to write the dual vectors again as column vectors.

In the case of the example, we have $v_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $v_2 =\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix}$, which gives us
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then
$$B=A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1\\0&1\end{bmatrix},$$
so the dual basis vectors will be $\phi_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1&-1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\phi_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Check that $\phi_1(v_1)=\phi_2(v_2)=1$ and $\phi_1(v_2)=\phi_2(v_1)=0$.

Comment: Thanks Ted for answering! I've always found it odd that sometimes we represent vectors as column vectors and think of row vectors as linear maps, but sometimes we don't. Is this a matter of preference or is there some rigor behind all this? @ted-shifrin

Comment: We tend to be typographically lazy and write $(a,b)$ instead of $(a,b)^\top$ or the column vector. But since almost all the world computes $A\vec x$ rather than $\vec xA$, we need vectors to be columns. … BTW, since you’re new, let me bid you welcome and remind you to accept answers once you’re satisfied. :)

Answer (score 1):

The vectors in a (finite dimensional) real vector space are column vectors. The vectors in the dual space are linear functions from $V$ to the real numbers. But, you can also represent them as row vectors. When you do this, the function represented by $\varphi = (a_1 \cdots a_n) \in V^*$ is:

$$f_{\varphi}(v) = \varphi v$$

This uses matrix multiplication. So if $v = (b_1 \cdots b_n)^T$ then the output will be:

$$a_1 b_1 + \cdots + a_n b_n$$